# How to prepare an NSURL from an NSString continaing international characters?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsurl

I have to access a web server using a `GET` with international characters (Hebrew in my case but could be anything).
So I make an `NSString` just fine but

```
[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]; // returns nil.
```

I realize I probably have to convert the international characters to percent codes.

Is there a built in method in Objective-c to do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes there is, you need `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This would ensure `NSURL *url` does not return `nil` because of the `"|"` in the `urlString`.

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.service.com/Service.svc?sort=name|ascending"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSURL` directly without `NSString`:

```
//.h file

@interface NewsBrowser : UIViewController {
    UIWebView *webView;
    NSURL *NewsUrl;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSURL *NewsUrl;

@end

//.m file

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:NewsUrl]];
```

Just pass a `NSURL` from another view (using `NewsUrl` variable) to this view.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSURL*) URLWithStringWithSpecialChars:(NSString *)sURL
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];
    if(url == nil)
        return [NSURL URLWithString:[sURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    else
        return url;
}
```

calling this function instead of URLWithString: should ensure that a valid NSURL is always returned (instead of nil when needed)