# Xcode converting special characters(NSString) to NSData

Tags: ios, xcode, special-characters, nsdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prepare an NSURL from an NSString continaing international characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418754/how-to-prepare-an-nsurl-from-an-nsstring-continaing-international-characters)

I've an issue with converting special characters into NSData format.

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.???.com/1.php?test=你好"];

NSLog(@"%@", strURL);

// to execute php code
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

NSLog(@"%@", dataURL);
```

When I print out the dataURL, the result is (null) whereas when my strURL is in English, it'll print the correct data it's supposed to print.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you sure the location contains data?

Comment: What location are you referring to ?

Comment: The url that the data is supposed to be fetched from.

Comment: Yes, the php code purely gets the variable to print it back out. But the dataURL is showing me (null)

Comment: Is it even making a request to your URL? Does `[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]` return nil?

Comment: Yes it's making a request, when i key in "abc", it does show some values, only with special characters that it shows (null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to add UTF-8 to your string

```
[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```